# How to choose the keywords correctly

Tags: html, seo, search-engine, keyword

I'm researching keywords for the meta tag of a website.

If I add "foo bar" is this the same as if I added "foo" and "bar" in the keyword content field?

I know we can add words and phrases in the content, but I'm asking if the two will have the same ranking when the user is searching for "foo bar" in a search engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of what i know, they rank different. Here is a reference
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/general/meta-tags-and-seo/

Comment: So of what I've read, the meta keyword tag isn't used anymore... But thank for the tip!

Comment: @BrunoPinho keywords are not used by google, but still by some other SE